# Which helmet is this character wearing in Star Trek Online?

Tags: star-trek-online

Which helmet is this?

[image]

The visor consistently scrolls to the side, like the Intel Uniform visor, but over the whole frontal surface.

The upper part of the uniform seems to be the [Terran Task Force Armor](https://sto.gamepedia.com/Uniform/Terran_Task_Force_Armor), but the helmet doesn't match.

I already looked through [this list](https://sto.gamepedia.com/Uniform) and the [costumes from the Lobi crystal consortium](https://sto.gamepedia.com/Lobi_Crystal_Consortium#Costumes), but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it at last:

[image]

It's an addition from the Discovery era season.

- Head

  - Category: *Helmet - DSC Tactical*
  - Covering: *Discovery Tactical Helmet*
  - Visor: *Interface*